# Open and close div popup of chat bubble button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a chat bubble buttons for website and mobile users. I have created a html code.

```
<div class="devsol-chat">

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="float" id="menu-open">
    <img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'buttons/chat.svg'; ?>">
    </a> 

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="float" id="menu-close">
    <img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'buttons/close.svg'; ?>">
    </a>            

    <ul>    
        <li><a href="https://m.me/kidsfitter" id="menu-facebook">
        <img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'buttons/facebook.svg'; ?>">
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="https://wa.me/923038513000" id="menu-whatsapp">
        <img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'buttons/whatsapp.svg'; ?>">
        </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want when user click the chat button then it popups with whatsapp and facebook buttons and also close buttons appears. Like these samples

[image]
and when user click it popups with close button
[image]

I want to use jquery or JavaScript to make it functional. Someone please help

Answer (score 2):

I won't code it for you because you won't learn the logic which is most important thing to have. I will explain it tho.

Okay so. You have 4 buttons.

Open chat
Close chat
Facebook
WhatsApp

By default Facebook and WhatsApp are hidden which is `display: none`.

When you click **Open chat** then **Facebook** and **WhatsApp** need to be visible which is `display: block`

When you click **Close chat** button they need to be hidden again which is `display: none`

So by analyzing this info we realized that we need to detect click on **Open chat** or **Close chat** with javascript, and after we detected it we need to get elements that we need to show or hide and set their css accordingly.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  //do something here
})
```

That function is all you need for one button to work. Take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp). It will help you with css. Come back here with some code so we can work it out :)

Happy coding

**EDIT**

Approach with `display: block` and `display: none` is easiest. There are other ways to do it if you want animations and stuff but you will understand that alone after you do this. Trust me :)